# What about the incarnation?

Tags: discussion

While the topic and inclusion of the incarnation is (reasonably) acceptable on Christianity SE, I am perplexed why it is so often included and referenced on BHSE when it has zero Biblical/scriptural credibility.

Sure it has much traditional support, but that again, is not what the site’s title suggests it should be about here.

What is the alleged incarnation?

- God became a man
- The word was God (John 1) so that mistakenly means Jesus is God too. Never mind that 1John says otherwise and the word was *with* God, meaning it cannot also *be* God.

No scripture supports these ideas except by an eisegetical approach that holds premise/creed before scripture, and welcomes reading into the text the ideas that do not originate from scripture, but many years after the original appointed authors.

Has BHSE lost its way? Perhaps, because the site is predominantly Trinitarian, these core parameters were never relevant to the title *Biblical* and *Hermeneutic*?

Comment: I have voted to close this question as it is opinion based. This also appears to be the conclusion of the two (Moderator-provided) answers at the present time of this comment. It is also plainly an attempt to censor the site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it presents substantial sections of misinformation as fact about this topic and the site community.

Comment: The Latin word, "incarnation" simply means "enfleshment" and is based in John 1:14, 1 John 4:2, 2 John 7, etc, "became flesh", regardless of what you think "logos" means in that place.

Comment: @Dottard like many words, their understanding and use can be quite different from the original intention. "the embodiment of God the Son in human flesh", is what is *intended* by the terms use which is totally baseless scripturally. Given that the "God the Son' is a fictitious construct.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to agree with interpretations of verses like John 1:1 & 14 as indicating the incarnation of a pre-existing Word who is God becoming human, but you *should be able to see how others can interpret it that way*.

Everyone's theology has some verses that fit well and others that are perplexing. But if someone was unable to see *any* support for positions other than their own, then I would question how well they're actually reading the texts. It seems to me that an inability to see any possible competing readings is actually a sign that the text is being forced to conform to outside theology, i.e., eisegesis.

Comment: Yes, I can see how others read it that way, but it is possible and coherent only to the contradiction of the rest of scripture. But it’s not about me or them, the site’s parameters are misleading to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

As a Site Moderator, I always aim to be impartial around different viewpoints on biblical texts and theology. I was formerly an atheist, and have changed my mind on **many ideas** based on many scriptures over the years, and love to see a range of viewpoints and opinions on the site. I strongly agree that we should not read ideas into texts which originated many hundreds of years later.

I recognise that I still have my own biases and blind spots, but so do we all, and so it's important for *all of us* to take great care with how we handle them. Some of my own bias will probably leak out here, but I aspire to handle this as a student of history rather than as a Christian.

### What did the earliest recipients understand?

Hermeneutics, at its core, typically boils down to questions of *what the author intended to mean* and *what the first recipients understood by it*. Besides being the most common understanding of these texts for many centuries, the concept of Jesus as God (and thus, the incarnation) is one of the earliest and frequently attested understandings, clearly going back at least to Ignatius of Antioch at the turn of the first century:

> "Ignatius, who is also called Theophorus, to the Church which is at Ephesus, in Asia, deservedly most happy, being blessed in the greatness and fullness of God the Father, and predestinated before the ages of time, that it should be always for an enduring and unchangeable glory, being united and elected through the true passion by the will of **the Father, and Jesus Christ, our God**: Abundant happiness through Jesus Christ, and His undefiled grace." *Ignatius to the Ephesians, chapter 1*

Again in chapter 17, Ignatius talks about Jesus *breathing immortality into the church*:

> "For this end did the Lord allow the ointment to be poured upon His head, that He might breathe immortality into His Church."

And again, in chapter 18, he says it outright:

> "Where is the boasting of those who are styled prudent? **For our God, Jesus Christ**, was, according to the appointment of God, conceived in the womb by Mary, of the seed of David, but by the Holy Ghost. He was born and baptized, that by His passion He might purify the water."

### How do we date claims of Jesus' divinity?

I'm unsure as to how you personally understand the dating the rest of the New Testament - typically most texts are dated between 50-70CE, and then we have Ignatius and others who come along within the next 30-40 years, who were disciples of John and Peter and others.

Essentially, *even if we ignore every reference to an **incarnation** or the **divinity of Jesus** in the New Testament*, we are immediately faced in the very next texts that follow with clear black-and-white claims of Jesus' divinity. This appears to be a plain reading that early authors took from these texts, and from the Apostles who taught them, and how early recipients understood them - these were not a later invention.

Of course, Christians held a great variety of viewpoints over the early centuries, and it took centuries for most of these to coalesce to shared viewpoints - for which they leaned heavily upon the New Testament texts and the teaching of the Apostles which had been handed down from disciple to disciple over many decades. And so it's important to read every text and try to understand its original intent as best we can.

### Conclusion

First, viewpoints which perceive Jesus as God are attested as early as we could ever expect, and did not appear "100's of years after the original authors". Historically, there is a very strong case to understand this as the original viewpoint of established Christian leaders, and it was handed down through all successive centuries. For whoever chooses to take a different view, that's fine by me - but let's not pretend that it isn't one of the earliest views, and certainly by no means even a *minority* view. And so this question is based on a false premise, for a start.

Second, claiming the site is *predominantly Trinitarian* isn't really correct either - perhaps in terms of historical content, that's fair, but in terms of site administration there are often more non-Trinitarian site members actually handling many of the review queues - Closing questions, Reopening them, reviewing First Posts, and doing many other things. By volume I would also say that non-Trinitarian community members also generate as many or more Comments than other site users, and on many days of the week can be the dominant group active on the site.

Yes, Questions and Answers from orthodox Christian viewpoints tend to get more votes on the site, as there appears to be a larger number of less active users holding those viewpoints, but at the end of the day I know many members do upvote a wide range of posts and viewpoints, and so the balance is pretty good.

### Comments on the impact of this question on the site Community

All in all, this Question surprises me, and as far as I can tell is a poor reflection of both history and the current makeup of the BH.SE community. All viewpoints are welcome here on the site, and it's fantastic having a wider range of perspectives on the site from week to week. With that in view, targeting specific viewpoints like this is unhelpful to building the community.

I don't like seeing anybody trying to shut down one set of viewpoints or users, especially from an established member of the community. Going forward, it would be far better to see ideas for how to *improve* the experience for others, demonstrating inclusivity, kindness, fairness and respect.

Comment: Thx for your thoughtful response. Perhaps the issue stems from similar logic to, *a student of history*, which is not what BH is about. Christianity is about history and myriad influences apart from the Bible and that approach is warranted and accepted there. My point regarding incarnation is that while accepted within C.SE it is not part of an honest Biblical approach and should be treated as such by the mere title of the site.

Comment: @steveowen if we ignore Christianity for a moment, and thus the traditional "canon" agreed by later church councils, Ignatius and the other near-contemporary writings are still immensely useful for understanding how early recipients understood these texts - indeed, that's why we allow study of them on the site, and why NT scholars study them too. They're in scope because they're an essential element of the field of study

Comment: Maybe I'm just dull! All of what you just said is about Christianity. Yes, the understanding or varied interpretation of biblical texts is relevant, but the site says BIBLICAL H. not *other near-contemporary writings* which is where incarnation comes from.

Comment: @steveowen Yes, Christians were the recipients of these texts, and so it does matter how they originally understood them. If we read them today and take away a completely different meaning than the original audience, chances are that it's *us* who misunderstands them. When there has been so much disagreement over the meaning of biblical texts, every scrap of evidence available is important for understanding how they were first read. As you yourself implied, we really should be trying to avoid interpretations that didn't arise until hundreds of years later, should we not?

Comment: 'Incarnation' is simply a Latin phrase capturing John 1:14 - the Word (which is and was God, v1) became flesh (carne).

Comment: Ok, so we take one passage (ignoring the *was with* bit) and devise an unbiblical idea which contradicts all other NT writings- esp. 1John 1. Incarnation is an invalid interpretation from which most traditional doctrine arises - which brings us back to C-SE. So BH doesn't make any sense in this paradigm or the Title is misleading. If we accept the imposition of Latin into the Scriptures to derive an unbiblical foundation for *everything*, we should just merge the two sites and abandon the hollow aspirations of BH.

Comment: Forgetting *with* then, if the word was God and became flesh, that's *incarnation* - God becoming flesh. I'm not sure what you're complaining about. Philippians 2:6-8 says the same thing, Colossians 1:15 again, Isaiah 9:6, and others. And clearly first century Christians like Ignatius *(a disciple of John, the author of our passage, no less!)* had been instructed in the same teaching. You basically have to go through the New Testament and earliest Christian witnesses with a big black marker pen if you want to maintain it's not an authentic early church understanding of these texts.

Comment: @steveowen - with respect, because you approach all these texts with *prior determination* that the incarnation "is an invalid interpretation", you're imposing your bias on the texts themselves, and are bluntly insisting that we must ignore all early witnesses that support it. You're throwing out the *baby* for distrust of the bathwater, as it were. The word we use today might come from Latin, but it's merely a representation of John 1 and various NT passages, and is strongly attested by the vast majority of early witnesses.

Comment: Ok, setting aside that those passages don't *actually* say what you suggest, but have been extrapolated to mean so, while creating contradictions throughout the NT- we are still focussed on doctrine and non-biblical writers - not bible. It would seem that either you cannot tell the difference (I don't believe that) or you are respectfully, just holding the official line.  Sound hermeneutics does not ignore context or the bulk of scripture to hold a contrived view regardless. Obviously, this is going nowhere so happy to leave it there. Thx again for the chat.

Comment: Sure thing @steveowen - I think the whole biblical/nonbiblical writer line is a red herring. In an important sense *biblical hermeneutics* is a **secular** discipline - ignoring faith, when interpreting ancient texts why should anybody care which ones were or weren't chosen by fourth century church fathers to be included in their "canon"? Speaking from a faith perspective, Ignatius' letter is not *inspired* as John's Gospel is. But it was written by John's own disciple, and so his perspective is the closest thing we'll get to an authentic/trustworthy view on John's authorial intent.